# Microsoft Graph access token refresh

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am writing an application that uses the "OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow" to get an access token for calling the Microsoft Graph API. The application authenticates as itself, not on behalf of a signed in user.

I based my code off of this [example from Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/blob/master/src/Program.cs).

This is how I initialize the GraphServiceClient:

```
    // Read application settings from appsettings.json (tenant ID, app ID, client secret, etc.)
    AppSettings config = AppSettingsFile.ReadFromJsonFile();

    // Initialize the client credential auth provider
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(config.TenantId, config.AppId, config.ClientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

And this is how I later use it (for example):

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

My application is an API. It is not an application that runs once and done. It will be continuously running for a long time. So I am concerned about what will happen when the access token expires. How do I make sure that when I need to use the graphClient the access token will not be expired?

Comment: Your question does not show how you are using the class or the token. Are you using the Access Token independently of the class? Otherwise, the **GraphServiceClient** will fetch new access tokens as required. The class method **AcquireTokenSilentAsync** will refresh the token if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using the access token independently of the class. Just using the class. I updated my post to show how I use the GraphServiceClient.

Could you point me to any documentation that explains this process of AcquireTokenSilentAsync automatically refreshing the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code snippet above, I think you are using the [graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) and using the client credential flow as the authentication.

So we are no need to generate access token here but just using the `graphClient` to call the graph api and gather the information you needed. And due to this mode, it won't appear the `token expired` situation as each time you call an api you will `new clientSecretCredential` before it.

And let's come back to the `refresh`, azure ad provide refresh token for refreshing the access token when it expired as refresh token has much longer expire time than access token, when we try to get the refresh token, we need to append `offline_access` to the scope [when generate the access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-2). But using client credential flow means your app requests a new token with it's own credentials, so it's no need to using refresh token to avoid making signed-in user sign in again. Using credential flow [shouldn't return refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3).

[image]

Then you may have some ideas that you insist on using `refresh the expired token` process, then what you only can do is generate an access token first and save the [token with its expired time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.accesstoken?view=azure-dotnet#properties) in some place, and using the access token as the http request header and calling graph api. Then the code should like this, but I don't think you're willing to using this kind of code, you may also refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet) for more details:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "your_azuread_clientid";
var clientSecret = "corresponding_client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;

//using http sender with the token
httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token );
// Call the web API.
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUri);
...
}
```

Comment: You say "as each time you call an api you will new ClientSecretCredential() before it."
However that is not how I am currently doing it. I do not create a new ClientSecretCredential() each time I call the graph API. Instead, the code snippet in my question is from the constructor of a singleton service in my ASP.NET web api. So I instantiate ClientSecretCredential() and GraphServiceClient() once, and then each time I receive a request that requires me to call the graph api, I use this.graphClient. Is this alright?
Or should I create a new ClientSecretCredential() each time I call graph api?

Comment: @gonzaleznicolas Thanks for your reply and I think you should  `create a new ClientSecretCredential() each time I call graph api` as you said. If you wanna keep using an access token until it's expired, you need to write the code to get and store the access token, and you also need to write code to check if the access token is expired, writing code to re-generate access token when the previous one is expired as well.

Comment: Thanks. So you are suggesting that each time I need to make call to the MS graph API I create a `new ClientSecretCredential()` and a `new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);`?
Is it acceptable practice to create a new GraphServiceClient for each request?

Comment: Sure, at least I think it's acceptable and I didn't find any official document to said it's not recommended.