# What type of ApplicationBuilder should I use in MSAL.NET? I'm using ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

What I'm trying to achieve is to popup a login browser from MSAL.NET, enter username and password, and used the access token to access Microsoft Graph.

Right now I used PublicClientApplicationBuilder to execute AcquireTokenInteractive to popup the login by MSAL.

I'm using ASP.NET Core Web Api.

The problem is, I'm having issue using PublicClientApplicationBuilder when deployed to IIS. It just stucks and always in Pending state.

Below is my sample code that always in Pending state when deployed to IIS:

```
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

        var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

And now I read an article from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/91715/msal-acquiretokeninteractive-code-hangs-infinte-lo.html
To use the ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder. Now the problem is there is no execute in ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder to popup login browser from MSAL just like the AcquireTokenInteractive.

There are only AcquireTokenSilent, AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode, AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf, and AcquireTokenForClient. But all of these don't seem to popup a login browser from MSAL.NET

Below is my sample code:

```
        var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
         .Create(clientId)
         .WithTenantId(tenantId)
         .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
         .Build();

        var result = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

How do I manage to popup a login browser from MSAL by using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder?

Comment: What is your front-end? Is it just ASP.NET Core Razor views? Or is there a single page app framework (React etc.)?

Comment: Im using Angular as a front-end. But I want the MSAL executed on the Back-end using C#. Would this be possible?

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero impossible

Comment: Using Angular as the frontend, you should integrate msal in the frontend, and including the sign in flow. After the users signed in, you can then generate access token to call the ms graph api. Here's the official sample :  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization-I/1-call-graph/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first know about MSAL. You have an asp.net core web app, and you wanna your user to sign in in a popup window and generate access token to call Ms graph api, so you need to refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp-calls-graph) to integrate azure ad into your web application.

What you mentioned in the question about `having issue when deployed to IIS` comes from using error method. When you test in your local side with those code, your local computer becomes the sever, it is supposed to work, but if you published the app to IIS, that means the users are hit your app in the client side but the pop up action will appear in the sever side. That's why it always pending.

To sum up here, if you need your users signed in and generate access token with delegate api permission, you should follow the document I post above to realize the feature. But if you can use application permission to generate access token as well, you can then go to use [graph SDK with client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to realize it.

Comment: Hi Tiny, about the issue on always pending on IIS. Is there any work around that you can suggest to make it working on IIS? And also the link above you send. I won’t need to use Azure AD Authentication. This will be on our application side. We only need the access token to access graph api thats why we use MSAL.

Comment: Im also using Angular for our client side. The Asp.net core is our API.

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero I think how to solve the issue is based on the target graph api supports which kind of [api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). If it supports `Permission type: application`, then you can using client credential flow to access the graph api, because using this flow don't need to let user enter user id and password, so it will work on IIS

Comment: The issue or requirement is that you wanna your api application worked in IIS, so it really need to use client credential flow but not other flows here. And certainly, you are no need to generate access token any more, just using graph SDK.

Comment: refer the code snippet in my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270742/15581227).

Comment: For example, if the api only support `Permission type: Delegated`, that means you need users to sign in first and generate access token with user identity, then calling the graph api with the token as the request header in your angular app, there's no other ways to solve it but refer to the sample mentioned in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#single-page-applications). But if your api supports application permission, you can refer to my another answer mentioned above.

Comment: But here is some scenario about login on our application side. User is registered to Azure AD and is also registered to our application side. Once the MSAL login popups and successfully authenticated, then we will login it also on our application side and save the access token from MsAL in order to access the graph api. This is what Im trying to implement.

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero What you said doesn't meet the design of azure ad. You should know that the `signed in process` should always start in the client side and authorized in the server side, you used azure ad as the authorization tool, so the flow should become start in the client and sending request to azure identity module(the pop up window), then after login successfully the popup window redirect to your own page. Any pop up in the sever side are incorrect. If you need to call graph api in your api application, you can only send the token as a parameter from angular app to api application

Comment: thanks for the information man. Appreciate it. I’ll comment here if I have any other questions. I’ll try to check some links you commented above.

Comment: @AnthonyEarlR.Cuartero sure, feel free to update here or in your question. thanks for your reply sir